# Compare two std::string like strcmp would do

Tags: c++, string, comparison, string-comparison

Have a look at the following piece of code

```
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char cstr[8] = {'t','e','s','t','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
    std::string str1;
    str1.assign(std::begin(cstr), std::end(cstr));
    assert(str1.length() == 8);
    std::string str2("test");
    assert(str2.length() == 4);

    // Unexpected
    assert(str1 != str2);
    assert(str1.compare(str2) != 0);

    // Expected
    assert(strcmp(str1.c_str(), str2.c_str()) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

In VS 2013 all the assertions pass, which might be surprising at a first glance. However, I believe if one reads the specification of each involved method carefully enough it becomes clear that this is indeed the intended behavior. But is it the expected one? I would argue that it is not. Is there an easy way to compare two *std::string* objects like *strcmp()* would do?

Comment: You mean: other than `strcmp(str1.c_str(), str2.c_str())`? If you want the behavior of C-style strings, this combination does not seem at all unreasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do that comparison:

- Keep your strings normalized and use `operator==` (Don't add unneeded trailing null terminators).
- If for some reason you *really* need bonus trailing null terminators, use `strcmp`.

Comment: One might not know the source of two std::string instances, so option two might be the way to go